# pandas select rows based on multiple datetime columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns `StartTime` and `EndTime`, I need to select events occurring between 7-9 and 18-20. What I tried so far is this:

```
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|            |                StartTime       |            EndTime            |
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|        25  | 2018-05-17 11:52:21.769491600  | 2018-05-17 23:08:35.731376400 |
|        32  | 2018-05-19 14:22:24.141359000  | 2018-05-19 18:37:04.003643800 |
|        42  | 2018-05-22 08:25:01.015975500  | 2018-05-22 22:32:34.249869500 |
|        43  | 2018-05-22 08:46:06.187427200  | 2018-05-22 21:29:17.397438000 |
|        44  | 2018-05-22 13:38:37.289871700  | 2018-05-22 18:38:36.498623500 |
+------------+--------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

I extracted hours from data used them to calculate following

```
df = df[((df['start_hr']<=7) & (df['end_hr']>=9)) | ((df['start_hr']<=18) & (df['end_hr']>=20))]
```

Is there a more accurate and fast alternative to it?

Comment: Hi, did you add a look at the between time function ? [https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will increase your memory consumption for a while but you can do something like this where you create two temp columns and use "df.query" on them. Make sure to delete the columns later.

```
df = df.assign(start_hr=df.start_hr.dt.hour, end_hr=df.end_hr.dt.hour)

df.query('(start_hr <= 7  and end_hr >=9) or (start_hr <= 18  and end_hr >=20) ')
```

Comment: good one, but since you are here, can you tell me if this logic will work if want to get all those events, that occur during this time. e.g. I want all active event during this time. whether it starts before 7 or after like 8 hrs and end after 9 , I modified my query as`df.query('((start_hr <= 7  and end_hr >=9) or start_hr==8) or ((start_hr <= 18  and end_hr >=20) or start_hr==19) ')`

Comment: @M_S_N yeah, I dont see why not

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
df['start_hr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_hr']) 
df['end_hr'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_hr'])

df['start_hr_day'] = df['start_hr'].dt.day
df['end_hr_day'] = df['start_hr'].dt.day 

df.loc[((df['start_hr_day']<=7) & (df['end_hr_day']>=9))|((df['start_hr_day']<=18) & (df['end_hr_day']>=20))]
```

Comment: i think it will skip the one that occured in between the given ranges i.e for 7-9, 8 will not be included